Statement to add a row to a table based on existence of another (DB2 LUW)?
I have a table, call it SHOPPING_LIST, where I have columns such as SHOPPER_ID, ITEM, UNIT_MEASURE, QTY.
The table could have rows like such:

PAUL, BANANAS, BUNCH, 1
PAUL, PLANTAINS, BUNCH, 2
PETER, PLANTIANS, BUNCH, 4

If there does not exist a row for BANANAS (as in the case with shopper PETER), then I want to insert a new row for BANANAS for shopper PETER with the QTY of PLANTAINS that PETER wanted to buy.  Or update the row to change it from PLANTAINS to BANANAS.  BUT Note that there is a CONSTRAINT that prevents a shopper from having more than one row for an ITEM.  So I can only insert or update if BANANAS doesn't already exist for PETER.
If a shopper has both BANANAS and PLANTAINS as shopping list items (as in the case with shopper PAUL), I want to simply delete the row with PLANTAINS for PAUL because he will buy BANANAS instead.  But I also want to update the QTY of BANANAS to match the QTY of PLANTAINS before the row gets deleted.
I tried using MERGE INTO but was having trouble.  I need to accomplish this in a DB2 LUW complaint SQL statement (or multiple statements) rather than a Procedure.

What problems did you have using merge? Merge can insert or update.
For the delete you could use a before trigger.
